# Array containing dynamic sub-arrays; only capturing the last sub-arry

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've been beating my head against this wall for a day and a half now.  I have a need to feed an array into a labeling script.  The labeling script works fine, which I have verified by using a statically written array.  The required array contains sub-arrays which are pulled dynamically from a mysql query.

A var_dump shows me that the mysql query is indeed pulling all pertinent records.  However I run into problems when trying to create a master array which contains ALL of these sub-arrays. It only wants to create a master array with the LAST sub-array pulled.  I'm hoping that description puts you on the right track.  Now for some code:

```
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($get_labels))
         {
           foreach($row as $key => $value)
                                  { 
            $addresses=array(
                array(
                    "name" => $row['title1'],
                    "address_1" => $row['Street_No'],
                    "address_2" => $row['Street'],
                    "city" => $row['City'],
                    "state" => $row['State'],
                    "zipcode" => $row['zip']
                    )
                    );
                     }
            }
```

Here is a sample var_dump of the above code:

```
    array(1) { [0]=> array(6) { ["name"]=> string(12) "PERSONS NAME" 
    ["address_1"]=>string(4) "7006" ["address_2"]=> string(12) "N HOLIDAY DR"   
    ["city"]=> string(9) "SOMECITY" ["state"]=> string(2) "ST" 
    ["zipcode"]=> string(5) "00000" } }
```

And the output as processed by the label script:

```
    PERSONS NAME
    7006 N HOLIDAY DR
    SOMECITY, ST 00000
```

Now here's the real question -- how do I write the above code so that get:

```
    array(2 or more) { [0]=> array(6) { ["name"]=> string(12) "PERSONS NAME" 
    ["address_1"]=>string(4) "7006" ["address_2"]=> string(12) "N HOLIDAY DR"   
    ["city"]=> string(9) "SOMECITY" ["state"]=> string(2) "ST" 
    ["zipcode"]=> string(5) "00000" }{ [1]=> array(6) { ["name"]=> string(12) 
    "ANOTHER DUDE" ["address_1"]=>string(4) "7125" ["address_2"]=> string(12) 
    "N HOLIDAY DR" ["city"]=> string(9) "SOMECITY" ["state"]=> string(2) "ST" 
    ["zipcode"]=> string(5) "00000" } ...and so on, as long as the query runs }
```

This would output on the label script like so:

```
    PERSONS NAME                    ANOTHER DUDE
    7006 N HOLIDAY DR               7125 N HOLIDAY DR
    SOMECITY, ST 00000              SOMECITY, ST 00000
```

The label script is fine, it is the script above that feeds the label script which I need help debugging.

I sure hope someone can help me.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: would love you to have a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: I did look at this, thank you.  When I used Jack's suggestion below the first time, I got every array iterated 12 times.  What a mess!  Then I removed the foreach statement entirely and used only the while loop, which worked perfectly.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of overwriting `$addresses` each time, you need to append to it:

```
$addresses[] = array(
    "name" => $row['title1'],
    "address_1" => $row['Street_No'],
    "address_2" => $row['Street'],
    "city" => $row['City'],
    "state" => $row['State'],
    "zipcode" => $row['zip']
);
```

Also, you don't need that inner `foreach`:

```
$addresses = [];
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($get_labels)) {
    $addresses[] = ...
}
```

Comment: A world class DUH moment for me!  Thank you very much Jack.  Once I used this and removed the foreach loop, I got perfect results.  Marvelous!

Comment: @BillIsaacs You're welcome; btw, it can't be said enough, but stop using the old `mysql_` functions :)

Comment: Jack, of course you're right, but I am not a full time php coder.  I'm the operations vp of a startup company.  I can't afford to have coders working for me, so I have to muddle through these things on my own.  When I get a little time to work on it, I'll make myself more familiar with php and the newer coding practices.  Thanks again.